# Help in using Moq

Tags: moq

I have a class that takes in a db factory.

```
public class ArticleManager
{
     private IDAOFactor _factory;

     public ArticleManager(IDAOFactory factory)
      {
            this._factory = factory;
       }

}
```

Using moq, how do I create an instance of ArticleManager?

I tried:

```
var mockFactory = new Mock<IDAOFactory>();
ArticleManager am = new ArticleManager(mockFactory);
```

But that isn't compiling.

Comment: IDAOFactory is decalred in var mockFactory as an interface, but I don't see it declared anywhere (unless you omitted it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mockFactory is a proxy class for moq. To expose the ArticleManager object instance within the mock, you'd use mockFactory.Object like so:

```
var mockFactory = new Mock<IDAOFactory>();
ArticleManager am = new ArticleManager(mockFactory.Object);
```